# RQuantLib: SET_VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'symbol'

Tags: c++, r

trying to run the following example code from 'RQuantLib' package...

```
require(RQuantLib)

HullWhite <- list(term = 0.055, alpha = 0.03, sigma = 0.01,
                  gridIntervals = 40)

Price <- rep(as.double(100),24)
Type <- rep(as.character("C"), 24)
Date <- seq(as.Date("2006-09-15"), by = '3 months', length = 24)
callSch <- data.frame(Price, Type, Date)
callSch$Type <- as.character(callSch$Type)

bondparams <- list(faceAmount=100, issueDate = as.Date("2004-09-16"),
                   maturityDate=as.Date("2012-09-16"), redemption=100,
                   callSch = callSch)
dateparams <- list(settlementDays=3, calendar="us",
                   dayCounter = "ActualActual",
                   period="Quarterly",
                   businessDayConvention = "Unadjusted",
                   terminationDateConvention= "Unadjusted")
coupon <- c(0.0465)

CallableBond(bondparams, HullWhite, coupon, dateparams)
```

...I get the following error:

```
SET_VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'symbol'
```

Wandering through Internet, I found something similar to my issue which has been solved by updating packages. I tried the same but no results; I tried it on three different computers, too :(

Two weeks ago the same code worked properly.
Any idea about what changed in the meantime?

Thanks :)

Comment: If it worked before, something must have changed in between. New R version, new version of the package, new operating system, etc. One of these is probably responsible for your issues.

Comment: Paul, could you confirm that code does not work under R 2.15.0 and it works under 2.15.1?

Following your suggestment, I noticed R 2.15.1 was released on 2012-06-22, but RQuantLib is featured by "Built: R 2.15.1; i386-pc-mingw32; 2012-08-06" at the bottom of the description file... Could that be the solution?

Comment: I do not have QuantLib installed, nor the time to do so. Is there anyone else who can check this? You could also just test it yourself by installing different R versions.

Comment: Trying to do so, unfortunately the computer I should use R with is not connected to Internet. Then it takes time to uninstall, re-install and update things.

In the meanwhile, I updated R on the machine I'm currently using and it seems to work: so I guess that the update to 2.15.1 is needed to use the latest version of RQuantLib.

Comment: [Cross-posted on R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-August/320962.html)